# Proper way to show the Fourier spectrum of an image

Tags: image, matlab, fft

I've taken the image of [lena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_S%C3%B6derberg) and performed scaling two different way. Does one of these images look better. This is kind of a subjective question, I just wasn't sure which would be better to use in a report.

The first image is in MATLAB and I used the following command

```
F = fftshift(fft2(lena))
uint8((log10(abs(F)+1)*(255/max(max(log10(abs(F)+1)))))
```

[image]

The second image was created in C++ using FFTW3, but then to scale the image I used ImageMagick

```
convert mag.png -contrast-stretch 0 -evaluate log 10000 mag-lognorm.png
```

[image]

Is one of these images a better representation of the fourier spectrum, does it not matter.

Comment: What information are you hoping to convey to the reader with this spectrum ? (If that's difficult to answer then perhaps you don't really need it ?)

Comment: Just as a general overview of the spectrum. I wasn't trying to pin point any part in particular. The second image loses all high frequency information, while the first muddles it all together and makes the lower information seem less important

Comment: I'm not sure that either of the spectra actually conveys any useful information, but I think I'd try messing with the contrast and get somewhere in between the two.

Comment: I agree that it is unclear what anyone would conclude from such a figure, but there are a couple of things you can try: crop the very high frequency and show the log-magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the second image is more meaningful, since it shows the decay of amplitude with spatial frequency. The first one gives the wrong impression that very high frequencies are present to the same extent as the low ones.